# SpatialLinesDataFrame (R): how to limit number of polygons in calculating distance between points and polygons

Tags: r, spatial-data-frame

I am looking to calculate the distance between points (about 47K) and the closest X countries (of all world countries). I have imported the lat/long of points as SpatialPoints, and loaded a world map as a SpatialPolygons. I think I could build off of the advice given here: 
[SpatialLinesDataFrame: how to calculate the min. distance between a point and a line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126998/spatiallinesdataframe-how-to-calculate-the-min-distance-between-a-point-and-a) 
It looks like I have to calculate the distance between all countries and all points and then extract the X closest, which is a bit intense with so many points. 
In short, is there a way to impose a polygon limit? If not, what would you suggest- my only thought is to import a smaller number of points and then loop through this code (I am a new R user). 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you working on a sphere using great-circle distances? Because that might make it a bit harder...

Comment: @Spacedman: I am not. I am just using cartesian distance between the points and a projected worldmap (wgs1984, i think). The process takes about an hour (better than Arc which is 5+), but the matrix is huge!

Comment: also, it appears that I am getting results for only 20 countries, but they do not seem to be the 20 nearest. Any ideas on how to make sure I cover all countries [but only keep results for the X nearest?] Otherwise taking the X nearest is impossible!

Comment: Time taken will depend on how detailed your world map is. If its come from a shapefile, how big is the .shp part of the shapefile? You may benefit from some line generalisation or simple thinning of the country boundaries. I don't understand the 20 countries problem.